# Using SQL Server Import/Export Wizard, File Hangs, SQL showing ASYNC_NETWORK_IO

Tags: sql, sql-server

Now, I have been using this tool for the last 4 years with csv files up to and around 2 million rows with absolutely 0 issues whatsoever.

All of a sudden today, a file (same type of file I run every week) is hanging at exactly row 2037 with no explanation.  I've checked all file constraints/db constraints and there's nothing that should or would be causing any issues.

I can freely query and do whatever else I need in the database, and I'm really really confused.

Below is the detailed message from the hung process in SSMS

```
INSERT bulk [dbo].[Calls]
       (
              [StartTime]         datetime,
              [EndTime]           datetime,
              [IpAddress]         nvarchar(100) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as,
              [TrunkId]           nvarchar(100) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as,
              [CallId]            nvarchar(100) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as,
              [SourceNumber]      nvarchar(15) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as,
              [DestinationNumber] nvarchar(15) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as,
              [Duration]          int,
              [CallRate] float,
              [CallCost] float
       )
       WITH
       (
              tablock,
              check_constraints
       )
```

As I watch it now, it does seem to actually eventually be allowing more rows--but it is taking SEVERAL very long minutes and only batching in 2000, then 500 records...Anybody have an idea?

As I finally was quitting and typing up this question, the package finished running successfully.

At this point, I'm just really really confused why a tiny 1 megabyte 5000 row file would cause these sorts of issues.

Comment: potential blocking or something.  is another source also utilizing dbo.calls and placing lock(s) on the table while your process is trying to use it?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no...
It seems to be consistently happening (not sure if its  unique to this file just yet), but I could try again and show the full activity log--there really isn't much going on, database is used once a week mostly ;)

Comment: look for other open connections running queries on those tables.  I really like [sp_whoisactive](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/09/sql-server-dba-scripts-how-to-find-slow-sql-server-queries/) if you haven't heard of it already.

Comment: If you are sure of your data try disabling all constraints and foreign keys on tables involved, it should speed things up by saving server's resources from checking constraints for each row. You can always correct your data if turning them back on will fail.